# What does "set iskeyword+=@-@" do?

Tags: vimrc

I'm looking at a file that has this in the .vimrc file:

`set iskeyword+=@-@`

I assumed it would let me delete a word with a hypen surrounded by two letters such as `this-word` with a `dw` command but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: OK, it looks like it adds `@` as a character so it will be considered part of the word. But I don't understand the syntax here. Why the `@` followed by a hyphen and another `@` sign?

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. Result of `set iskeyword` is `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,$,%,@-@,:` with a literal `@-@` in there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From `:h 'isk`:

```
See 'isfname' for a description of the format of this option.
```

Then from `:h 'isf`:

```
If the character is '@', all characters where isalpha() returns TRUE
are included.  Normally these are the characters a to z and A to Z,
plus accented characters.  To include '@' itself use "@-@".
```

So, as you said in your [comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/what-does-set-iskeyword-do#comment19906_11356), it seems that `@-@` stands for the `@` character itself.

As to why this syntax is used, I suppose the reason is because a single `@` is already used to denote `all characters where isalpha() returns TRUE`, which usually are `the characters a to z and A to Z, plus accented characters`. So, `@` couldn't be used to denote itself.

As a workaround, maybe the syntax used to express a range of characters was chosen instead.
The same syntax which is used, for example, to stand for all the alphabetical characters written in lowercase: `a-z`.

Maybe `@-@` could be interpreted as the range of characters between the `@` character, and the `@` character, that is only the `@` character and nothing else.

Answer (score 6):

Going deeper with vim's "pattern":

(content below mainly comes from neovim' s help )

## Character classes

The `character range`   matches a fixed set of characters.  
A `character class` is  similar, but the set of characters can be redefined without changing the `search pattern`.
For example, search for this pattern:

```
/\f\+
```

The "\f" item stands for file name characters.  Thus this matches a sequence of characters that can be a file name.  Which characters can be part of a file name depends on the system you are
using.

This is specified with the 'isfname' option.

Actually, Unix allows using just about any character in a file name,  including white space.
But it would make it impossible to find the end of a file name in text.

The character classes are:

```
    item    matches                     option ~
    \i      identifier characters       'isident'
    \k      keyword characters          'iskeyword'
    \p      printable characters        'isprint'
    \f      file name characters        'isfname'
```

`\I` is like `\i`, excluding digits. same for K P F

NOTE: the above also work for multibyte characters.

The ones below only match ASCII characters

```
                        *whitespace* *white-space*
\s  whitespace character: <Space> and <Tab>     */\s*
\S  non-whitespace character; opposite of \s    */\S*
\d  digit:              [0-9]       */\d*
\D  non-digit:          [^0-9]      */\D*
\x  hex digit:          [0-9A-Fa-f] */\x*
\X  non-hex digit:          [^0-9A-Fa-f]    */\X*
\o  octal digit:            [0-7]       */\o*
\O  non-octal digit:        [^0-7]      */\O*
\w  word character:         [0-9A-Za-z_]    */\w*
\W  non-word character:     [^0-9A-Za-z_]   */\W*
\h  head of word character:     [A-Za-z_]   */\h*
\H  non-head of word character: [^A-Za-z_]  */\H*
\a  alphabetic character:       [A-Za-z]    */\a*
\A  non-alphabetic character:   [^A-Za-z]   */\A*
\l  lowercase character:        [a-z]       */\l*
\L  non-lowercase character:    [^a-z]      */\L*
\u  uppercase character:        [A-Z]       */\u*
\U  non-uppercase character:    [^A-Z]      */\U*

    NOTE: Using the atom is faster than the [] form.

    NOTE: 'ignorecase', "\c" and "\C" are not used by character classes.

            */\_* *E63* */\_i* */\_I* */\_k* */\_K* */\_f* */\_F*
            */\_p* */\_P* */\_s* */\_S* */\_d* */\_D* */\_x* */\_X*
            */\_o* */\_O* */\_w* */\_W* */\_h* */\_H* */\_a* */\_A*
            */\_l* */\_L* */\_u* */\_U*
\_x Where "x" is any of the characters above: The character class with
    end-of-line added
(end of character classes)
```

## 'isfname' 'isf'

The characters specified by this option are included in file names (and path names)

default string:

```
1. Windows:  "@,48-57,/,\,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,{,},[,],:,@-@,!,~,="
2. therwise: "@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~,="
```

to see it more clear:

Under windows, you can use

```
@
48-57
/
\
.
-
_
+
,
#
$
%
{
}
[
]
:
@-@
!
~
=
```

other OS: same as above, except for:

```
\
{
}
[
]
:
@-@
!
```

### Filenames are used for

1. `gf` commands
2. `[i` commands 
   (Display the first line that contains the keyword under the cursor.  The search starts at the beginning of the file
   )
3. in  the tags file
4. `\f` in a |pattern|

only the characters <= 255 are specified with this option.
( Multi-byte characters 256 and above, are always included. For UTF-8, the characters 0xa0 to 0xff are included as well.)

The format of this option is a list of parts, separated with commas.
Each part can be

1. a single "character number", including:

- a  decimal number between 0 and 255
- the ASCII character itself (does not work for digits).

2. a range:  two  character numbers with '-' in between.  Example:

   `"_,-,128-140,#-43"` ,  meanings:

```
_
- (oh, looks like _)
the range 128 to 140
the range # to 43
```

If a part starts with `^` 
the following character number (or range)
will be excluded.
Put the excluded character after the range where it is included.

To include `^` itself, use it as the last character of the option or the end of a range.  Example:

`"^a-z,#,^"`    (exclude 'a' to 'z', include '#' and '^')

`@`:   looks like a, alphabet
represent  all characters    where isalpha() returns TRUE.    (see :alpha: ,  or  man isalpha )
about `isalpha()`:

```
checks  for an alphabetic character; 
in the standard "C" locale, it is equivalent to (isupper(c) || islower(c)).  
In some locales, there may be additional characters for which isalpha() is true:   letters which are neither uppercase nor lowercase. ( for example: accented characters. Such é, â, î)
```

To include `@` itself:   use `@-@`.

Examples:

- `"@,^a-z"`: All alphabetic characters, excluding lower  case ASCII letters.
- `"a-z,A-Z,@-@"`  :  All letters plus the '@' character.

A comma can be included by using it where a character number is  expected.  Example:

- `"48-57,,,_"`  :   Digits, comma and underscore.

A comma can be excluded by prepending a `^`
Example:

- `" -~,^,,9"`  :  All characters from space to '~', excluding  comma, including `<Tab>`

See |option-backslash| about including spaces and backslashes.

### On systems using a backslash as path separator, like Windows

Vim tries to  do its best to make it work as you would expect. But it is tricky.
Vim will **not** remove a `\` in front of a normal file  name character on these systems, (but it will on *nix)

### You'd better not put a space in 'isfname'.

Otherwise, Vim  doesn't know where a file name starts or ends when doing
**completion**

The  `&` and `^` are not included by default, because these are special for cmd.exe.

## 'isident'  (Maybe you should  change 'iskeyword' instead of 'isident'.

)
ident:  **identifiers**,  not indent

default:

1. Windows:    `"@,48-57,_,128-167,224-235"`
2. otherwise:  `"@,48-57,_,192-255"`

Identifiers are used in:

1. recognizing environment variables
2. after a match of the 'define' option.
3. `\i` in a  |pattern|.

(For `@`, only characters up to 255 are used)

If you change this option, it might break expanding  environment variables.  
E.g., if `/` is included, when Vim tries to  expand `"$HOME/.local/share/nvim/shada/main.shada"`,
something bad will happend.

## 'iskeyword' 'isk'

local to buffer

default

```
nvim :    "@,48-57,_,192-255"
Vi :      "@,48-57,_"

ps: no quotation mark in nvim's help here. strange.
```

Keywords are used in searching and recognizing with commands like:

- `[i`  (Display the first line that contains the keyword)
- `w`
- `*`
- `\k` in a |pattern|.

For `@`,  characters above 255 will check the **`word` character class**:   `\w`  
(`[0-9A-Za-z_]`, that is, any character that is not white space or punctuation)
(An underscore, `_`  , is a character, not punctuation. Although it is sometimes referred to as 'underline'. These days underscores are mostly used in passwords, e-mail addresses etc)

### For C programs you could use

`"a-z,A-Z,48-57,_,.,-,>"`

```
a-z
A-Z
digits
_
.
-
>
```

### For a help file (of vim)

it is set to all non-blank printable characters except
`*`, `"` and `|`

so that `CTRL-]` on a command finds the help for that
command.

This option also influences syntax highlighting, unless the syntax
uses |:syn-iskeyword|.

## 'isprint' 'isp'

global, string

default:

"@,161-255"

The characters given by this option are displayed directly on the
screen.

It is also used for `\p` in a |pattern|.  The characters from  space (ASCII 32) to '~' (ASCII 126) are always displayed directly,  even when they are not included in 'isprint' or (explicitly) excluded.

```
  0 -  31   "^@" - "^_" (Non-printable characters are displayed with two characters )
 32 - 126   always single characters
```

Illegal bytes from 128 to 255 (invalid UTF-8) are
displayed as `<xx>`, with the hexadecimal value of the byte.
When 'display' contains "uhex" all unprintable characters are displayed as `<xx>`.

The SpecialKey highlighting will be used for unprintable characters. |hl-SpecialKey|

Multi-byte characters 256 and above are always included, only the characters up to 255 are specified with this option.  When a character is printable but it is not available in the current font, a replacement character will be shown.

Unprintable and zero-width Unicode characters are displayed as `<xxxx>`.
There is no option to specify these characters.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case asked for in the original question:

> delete a word with a hypen surrounded by two letters such as this-word with a dw command

... you want to add `-` as a word character, like this:

```
:set iskeyword+=-
```

To change it back to the defaults, do this:

```
set iskeyword&
```

And if you want easy access to flexible definitions of what counts as a word, you could try using keybindings as shortcuts. Some of these are heuristics; don't take it for granted they will work exactly how you want! But ideas for your `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Add various charcters to the list of word characters, for \< \> searches and
" for motion commands like cw diw etc.
nnoremap <leader>/- :set iskeyword+=-<CR>
nnoremap <leader>/= :set iskeyword+==<CR>
nnoremap <leader>// :set iskeyword+=/<CR>
nnoremap <leader>/; :set iskeyword+=;<CR>
nnoremap <leader>/: :set iskeyword+=:<CR>
" common filenames (heuristic)
nnoremap <leader>/f :set iskeyword+=.,#,-<CR>
" common full path (heuristic)
nnoremap <leader>/p :set iskeyword+=.,#,/,~,-<CR>
" urls (heuristic)
nnoremap <leader>/u :set iskeyword+=:,/,.,~,?,=,:,;,#,&,+,-<CR>
" shell variables (heuristic)
nnoremap <leader>/v :set iskeyword+=$,{,},[,]<CR>
" make words be whitespace-delimited, like WORD
nnoremap <leader>/W :set iskeyword=!-~<CR>
" restore default definition of words
nnoremap <leader>/w :set iskeyword&<CR>
```

Or for a more powerful and flexible solution, consider using the [kana/vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) plugin.